# "Digital Clutch" For Electric Motor

Tags: torque, ac-motor

I am in the design phase of a piece of machinery that needs a "Digital Clutch."

Requirements of the project: 
Machine must run at several different constant RPM settings. 
Machine needs to ability to "sense" a jam based on the motor load/torque
Clutch Sensitivity must be able to be digitally changed on the controller for various work loads.

Project will be made with a low horsepower motor(1-3HP), running on 110v.

I am stumped as to how to measure the apparent load in order to stop the machine should a jam occur.

One thought I had was using a speed controller to measure the RPMs, and designing the controller to sense a change in current, thus being able to I believe measure a change in load.

While I've scoured Google for equations, I think I'm missing something and there may be an "easy" solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: *One thought I had was using a speed controller to measure the RPMs, and designing the controller to increase the voltage if the RPMs drop ...* Why would you increase the voltage when the system jammed? That's that would increase the torque and give the opposite of what you are looking for. Instead, see if you can apply a torque limit through your variable frequency drive and then check that it and the motor can sustain this situation for a long time.

Comment: Can you look at the current being drawn by the motor?  That would be my first approach.

Comment: @Transistor - Thanks for our insight. You are absolutely right about the increase in voltage. I was thinking more theoretically. I would never in practice increase the voltage as that would make the jam worse or break things.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis - This may work. I'll look into this more.

Comment: _"Project will be made with a low horsepower motor(1-3HP)"_ - do you have a particular motor in mind?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I do not, however I was thinking about a 3000 RPM motor with a planetary gear box to bring it down to around 300 RPMs. 

The more I study this out, a DC motor may be the way I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a variable frequency drive (VFD) with a three-phase induction motor or permanent magnet synchronous motor (AKA brushless DC motor). The motor will not be available with a 110 V rating. You can get VFDs that will convert 110 V, single-phase to 230 V, three-phase. However, the features that you need, may be available only in models that are designed for 3-phase input.

It seems that you want to set a maximum torque based on your knowledge of a particular load. If the operating torque reaches the set limit, power to the motor must be instantly electronically cut off as if disengaging a mechanical clutch. There are many VFDs on the market that can do that. For the best performance, a motor shaft speed/position sensor may be required, but there is a good possibility that you won't need one.

You need to investigate the reputations of VFD suppliers in your area. Local support is valuable. There are a number of VFD manufacturers that are known throughout the world. The best ones have technical literature that explain the capabilities of their products. Find ones that have good support in your area, download their literature and study it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different kinds of "digital clutch" in the industrial world. I can't see which really you need, or if you really need it. From your description, the only thing you need is to sense the output torque. This property is available on the VFD/induction motor running in vector control or on PMSM/servo drive.

Once upon the jam is detected, then what? This information is missing.

Various RPM settings: If the minimal velocity is near 0 rpm, then PMSM/Servo is better than IM/Vector. Also the vector does it's best if it work in conjunction with motor encoder feedback.

Look for PLCopen standard blocks for Motion control. The very common function is MC_GearIn.

A clutch is a device that couples two shafts. Therefore there could not be any digital one, only digital gearboxes do exist they match the speed of two shafts.

Comment: If there is a jam the machine would stop and the operator alerted, jam cleared, process resumed. To your point, "Clutch" isn't a very accurate term for what I'm trying to do. 

Why I need it variable is that if I convert the line to a different item in the product line(once a week), some of the products need a higher torque to process properly.

I guess in a nutshell, while I want my RPM to remain constant, I want to be able to sense the amount of output torque in order to feel the jam and stop the motor. 

Thank you for your insight!